# How to display legend for hexagon fill colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am working on a hex bin plot in ggplot2. A legend is appearing for the filling of the hexagons (count) but not for what the hexagons are actually heat scaled on (the prediction).

How do I go away with the legend of the count but have it display what is actually being heat scaled (the prediction). Here is my code and a picture of what I am referring to.

```
FF1xBARHH <- ggplot(FFxBARHH, aes(x = plate_x, y = plate_z, z = Prediction)) +
  stat_summary_hex(fun = mean, bins = 9) +
  stat_summary_hex(geom = "text", aes(label = after_stat(value)), fun = length, 
                   bins = 9) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", midpoint = 0.240) +
  xlim(c(2,-2)) +
  ylim(c(0,5)) +
  coord_fixed(0.8)+
  labs(title = "Gerrit Cole Fastball April 2022 ExAVG Map RHH")+
  annotate('rect', xmin = -0.85, xmax = 0.85, ymin = 1.6, ymax = 3.5, 
           fill = 'black', color = 'black', alpha = 0.0001, size = 1)
```

[image]

```r
FFxBARHH <- structure(list(Prediction = c(0.002, 0.598, 0, 0, 0.688, 0.104, 
0.908, 0.042, 0.142, 0.872, 0.034, 0.916, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), pitch_type = c("FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", 
"FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", 
"FF", "FF", "FF", "FF", "FF"), game_date = structure(c(19112, 
19112, 19112, 19106, 19106, 19095, 19095, 19095, 19095, 19095, 
19095, 19090, 19112, 19112, 19112, 19106, 19106, 19095, 19095, 
19095, 19083, 19083), class = "Date"), release_speed = c(97.9, 
96.6, 96.2, 98, 95.4, 99.8, 97.5, 97.6, 96.8, 95.7, 94.7, 99.1, 
98.7, 98.1, 96.2, 97.7, 98.6, 99.3, 98.9, 97.9, 96.2, 96.8), 
    player_name = c("Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", 
    "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", 
    "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", 
    "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", 
    "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", 
    "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit", "Cole, Gerrit"), pitcher = c(543037, 
    543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 
    543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 
    543037, 543037, 543037, 543037, 543037), events = c("field_out", 
    "single", "field_out", "field_out", "field_out", "field_out", 
    "double", "field_out", "field_out", "double", "field_out", 
    "double", "strikeout", "strikeout", "strikeout", "strikeout", 
    "strikeout", "strikeout", "strikeout", "strikeout", "strikeout", 
    "strikeout"), description = c("hit_into_play", "hit_into_play", 
    "hit_into_play", "hit_into_play", "hit_into_play", "hit_into_play", 
    "hit_into_play", "hit_into_play", "hit_into_play", "hit_into_play", 
    "hit_into_play", "hit_into_play", "called_strike", "swinging_strike", 
    "called_strike", "called_strike", "foul_tip", "foul_tip", 
    "swinging_strike", "called_strike", "called_strike", "called_strike"
    ), zone = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4, 9, 
    9, 5, 6, 5, 9, 8, 6), des = c("Edward Olivares grounds out, second baseman Gleyber Torres to first baseman Anthony Rizzo.", 
    "Bobby Witt Jr.  singles on a sharp line drive to center fielder Aaron Hicks.", 
    "Bobby Witt Jr.  flies out to right fielder Giancarlo Stanton.", 
    "Oscar Mercado pops out to first baseman Anthony Rizzo in foul territory.", 
    "Owen Miller grounds out, second baseman Gleyber Torres to first baseman Anthony Rizzo.", 
    "Teoscar Hernandez grounds out, second baseman Gleyber Torres to first baseman Anthony Rizzo.   Vladimir Guerrero Jr.  to 3rd.", 
    "Vladimir Guerrero Jr.  doubles (1) on a line drive to right fielder Aaron Judge.", 
    "Alejandro Kirk grounds out sharply, shortstop Isiah Kiner-Falefa to first baseman Anthony Rizzo.", 
    "Lourdes Gurriel Jr.  grounds out sharply, second baseman Gleyber Torres to first baseman Anthony Rizzo.", 
    "Bo Bichette doubles (1) on a sharp line drive to center fielder Aaron Hicks.", 
    "Santiago Espinal flies out sharply to center fielder Aaron Hicks.", 
    "J.D. Martinez doubles (1) on a line drive to right fielder Aaron Judge.   Xander Bogaerts scores.", 
    "Bobby Witt Jr.  called out on strikes.", "Salvador Perez strikes out swinging.", 
    "Hunter Dozier called out on strikes.", "Amed Rosario called out on strikes.", 
    "Myles Straw strikes out on a foul tip.", "George Springer strikes out on a foul tip.", 
    "Matt Chapman strikes out swinging.", "Bo Bichette called out on strikes.", 
    "Jonathan Schoop called out on strikes.", "Miguel Cabrera called out on strikes."
    ), stand = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
    "R"), plate_x = c(0.07, 0.19, -0.62, 0.07, 0.24, 0.75, 0.21, 
    -0.42, 0.29, -0.19, -0.22, -0.2, 0.55, -0.3, 0.82, 0.46, 
    -0.03, 0.71, -0.24, 0.52, 0.1, 0.66), plate_z = c(3.26, 3.48, 
    3.08, 2.94, 2.74, 2.17, 2.01, 1.85, 2.58, 2.56, 2.75, 3.18, 
    2.41, 2.43, 1.75, 1.64, 2.73, 2.37, 2.34, 1.85, 1.93, 2.81
    ), launch_speed = c(95.9, 105.1, 86.2, 72.9, 106.7, 95.4, 
    91.8, 101.2, 104.2, 109.8, 100.4, 91.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), launch_angle = c(-10, 15, 56, 68, 4, 
    -15, 9, -10, 0, 13, 36, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fbc9f01eee0>)
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(FFxBARHH)` so we can run the code?

Comment: @JonSpring I edited the question and believe I included it! Let me know if this is not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that both the Predictions (mean) and the counts are shown together in one palette. If you define limits for the palette covering the range of the Preditions (I used `limits = c(-.1, .6)`) then the plot looks like you expected it, right?

```
ggplot(FFxBARHH, aes(x = plate_x, y = plate_z, z = Prediction))+
  stat_summary_hex(fun = mean, bins = 9) +
  stat_summary_hex(geom = "text", aes(label = after_stat(value)), fun = length,
                   bins = 9) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", 
                        midpoint = 0.240, 
                        limits = c(-.1, .6)) +
  xlim(c(2,-2)) +
  ylim(c(0,5)) +
  coord_fixed(0.8)+
  labs(title = "Gerrit Cole Fastball April 2022 ExAVG Map RHH")+
  annotate('rect', xmin = -0.85, xmax = 0.85, ymin = 1.6, ymax = 3.5, 
           fill = 'black', color = 'black', alpha = 0.0001, size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: It actually is still not filling the correct way using my dataset. Any idea on why this may be happening?

Comment: What do you expect to see? Currently it's the mean of your data per hexagon.