# Heat map is not scaling properly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to make a heat map in ggplot2 using stat_summary_hex. I asked the questions originally here:

[How to display legend for hexagon fill colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945798/how-to-display-legend-for-hexagon-fill-colour/75947255#75947255)

But cannot seem to get my heatmap to scale like the example. Everything is being under evaluated in mine which tells me it may not be taking the mean to fill the hexagons? Here is a sample of the code I am working with.

```
FFxBARHH1 <- data.frame("plate_x" = c("-0.20", "0.21", "-0.19", 
                                      "0.66", "0.10", "0.52"),
                  "plate_z" = c("3.18", "2.01", "2.56", "2.81", "1.93", 
                            "1.85"),
                  "Prediction" = c("0.916", "0.908", "0.872", "0.000", "0.000", 
                                "0.000"))

FFxBARHH1$Prediction<-  as.numeric(FFxBARHH1$Prediction)
FFxBARHH1$plate_x<-  as.numeric(FFxBARHH1$plate_x)
FFxBARHH1$plate_z<-  as.numeric(FFxBARHH1$plate_z)

ggplot(FFxBARHH1, aes(x = plate_x, y = plate_z, z = Prediction))+
stat_summary_hex(fun = mean, bins = 9) +
stat_summary_hex(geom = "text", aes(label = after_stat(value)), fun = length,
               bins = 9) +
scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", 
                   midpoint = 0.240, 
                   limits = c(0.0, 1.0)) +
xlim(c(2,-2)) +
ylim(c(0,5)) +
coord_fixed(0.8)+
labs(title = "Gerrit Cole Fastball April 2022 ExAVG Map RHH")+
annotate('rect', xmin = -0.85, xmax = 0.85, ymin = 1.6, ymax = 3.5, 
       fill = 'black', color = 'black', alpha = 0.0001, size = 1)
```

How can I get my visualization to correctly depict the mean value of prediction in each hexagon?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your expect output?

Comment: @Quinten I switched computers and ran the exact same code and got the expected output. Very odd, not sure what was going wrong on my end but I got it!